# Suppress syntax error or warning in bash_completion every time new terminal is opened?

Tags: bash, suppress-warnings, bash-completion

I enabled `bash_completion` in my `.bashrc` file. Now every time I start a terminal, it shows me this warning:

```
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: too many arguments
```

For more info, i ran this command:

```
$ bash .bashrc
```

And it show me this warning:

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
/etc/bash_completion.d/ifupdown: line 3: [: =: unary operator expected
/etc/bash_completion.d/ifupdown: line 19: [: =: unary operator expected
/etc/bash_completion.d/man: line 3: [: too many arguments
```

Line 50 of `/etc/bash_completion.d/gcc`:

```
[ $USERLAND = GNU -o $UNAME = Cygwin ] && \
```

I don't see what the problem is here? How do I suppress those warnings from coming up a the start of terminal.

**EDIT:**

I ran `bash -xv .bashrc` as suggested by Adrian and i found these in the output:

```
+++ '[' = GNU -o Linux = Cygwin ']'
/etc/bash_completion.d/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
.
.
.
+++ '[' = GNU ']'
/etc/bash_completion.d/ifupdown: line 3: [: =: unary operator expected
+++ '[' = GNU ']'
/etc/bash_completion.d/ifupdown: line 19: [: =: unary operator expected
```

**EDIT: 2**

Output of `bash -x /etc/bash_completion | grep -E 'UNAME|USERLAND'`

```
++ UNAME=Linux
++ UNAME=Linux
++ unset UNAME RELEASE default dirnames filenames have nospace bashdefault plusdirs
```

Comment: This probably happens because either `$USERLAND` or `$UNAME` is empty, debug with `bash -xv` to see what's going on under the hood. What system are you on?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth , I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I will try that out.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth if it's complaining of too many arguments, that would suggest that `$USERLAND` or `$UNAME` contain more than one word. I'm surprised that they're not quoted.

Comment: There's something ironic about a `bash` completion file that has a bug because it uses poorly written POSIX-compatible shell instead of the `bash` extension `[[ $USERLAND = GNU || $UNAME = Cygwin ]]`.

Comment: @TomFenech No, it can be both because of the way this is parsed but the `=: unary operator expected` hints that the left hand side is unset. `[ = FOO ]`<enter> => `-bash: [: =: unary operator expected`. `[ = FOO -o = BAR ]`<enter> => `-bash: [: too many arguments`.

Comment: `'[' = GNU -o Linux = Cygwin ']'` . @AdrianFrühwirth, this is what I found from the output. This means `$USERLAND` is empty, right? So how do I correct this?

Comment: Exactly...`UNAME` (and `USERLAND`) are set in `/etc/bash_completion` (`UNAME=$( uname -s )`) which should definitely always return something. *How* did you enable `bash_completion` in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: I had commented out the code in `.bashrc` which imported `bash_completion` when I first started with ubuntu(just a month back). Now I un-commented it.

Comment: Maybe my `bash_completion` file is corrupted. How do I reinstall it?

Comment: @Adrian Good point, I was only considering the single comparison. Note that the second warning in the question is from a different line in a different file.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, but it is kind of obvious that the errors stem from those same two variables being unset and the other files just `test` on one of them, hence the different error message ;-) (`USERLAND` in case of `ifupdown`, I just checked).

Comment: @udiboy Could be, but I doubt it. To reinstall you can try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion`.

Comment: Nope, reinstalling didn't help

Comment: @udiboy Please post the output of `$ bash -x /etc/bash_completion |& grep -E 'UNAME|USERLAND'`.

Comment: I checked my `bash_completion` file. `UNAME` is correctly set, but i didn't find any sign of `USERLAND` anywhere.

Comment: It should be set right below where `UNAME` gets set.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth its not set. I searched the whole file for `USERLAND` but i didn't find any matches. And I also posted the output you requested

Comment: What version of `bash-completion` do you have installed (e.g. `dpkg -s bash-completion | grep Version`) and what `RELEASE` version does it say in `/etc/bash_completion`?

Comment: Version: 1:1.3-1ubuntu8.1
RELEASE: 20060301

Comment: I found this bug page https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=558127 but it doesn't help much. I can't figure out what he did exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After troubleshooting this with you I am pretty confident that you have files in `/etc/bash_completion.d` that belong to an older version of `bash-completion` and are thus not compatible with the version of `/etc/bash_completion` you have installed (or vice versa).

I suggest completely uninstalling `bash-completion`:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge bash-completion
```

and verifying that there are no files left afterwards:

```
$ find /etc/bash_completion*
```

If there are, delete them manually.

Afterwards re-install `bash-completion`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Comment: I did the `purge`, and I searched for `bash_completion*` . The `bash_completion.d` directory still exists with some files in it. But none of the three files which were giving me the error above are present. I figure these remaining files were added by other programs while i manually installed them(eg. `git`, `surfraw`). So do I remove these too? If so, will they be installed back when i install `bash-completion`

Comment: @udiboy Valid point...no, you don't want to touch these. Try reinstalling now.

Comment: YES! ERROR SOLVED! THANKS A TON!

Comment: OK, now `bash_completion` has the `USERLAND` declaration, right after `UNAME`. I wonder why `--reinstall` or `remove` then `install` wasn't working

Comment: @udiboy Because `remove` (unlike `purge`) doesn't touch config files, since those scripts are located in `/etc` they didn't get removed. Great it worked :-)

Comment: This solved a syntax error on the `_sudo` function for me.